# fs.openSync adding extra newline when writing stdout to file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a process that starts another process and writes its output to the file `out.log`

```
let out = fs.openSync(path.join(process.cwd(), './out.log'), 'a')
let err = fs.openSync(path.join(process.cwd(), './out.log'), 'a')

let child = cp.spawn('node', [path.join(__dirname, '../../server')], { detached: true, stdio: ['ignore', out, err, 'ignore'] })

child.unref()
```

The above then starts which does another spawn and this is where the output comes from:

```
server = cp.spawn('node', [path.join(process.cwd(), 'index.js')], { windowsHide: true })
server.stdout && server.stdout.on('data', chunk => console.log(chunk.toString()))
server.stderr && server.stderr.on('data', chunk => console.error(chunk.toString()))
```

The above works, it writes the output to the output file, however, it is adding extra newlines to the file so instead of output like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I am getting output like this:

```
line 1

line 2

line 3
```

To make the extra newlines go away, I need to change the `stdout: 'data'` event to use a replace:

```
server.stdout && server.stdout.on('data', chunk => 
  console.log(chunk.toString().replace(/\n$/, '')))
```

I don't feel this is a good approach to remove these extra newlines. Is there something I can do to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log`/`errror` will always add a newline at the end of its output. I'm guessing that whatever value you are receiving from the server process already has a newline.

So, I can see three possible solutions:

1. ensure that the server process strips its newline before sending
2. strip the newline in the node process before printing to the console.
3. Use [`process.stdout.write()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback), which writes to the process's stdout without a newline.

Comment: Using `process.stdout.write()` does it!